# Check For Existence Of Array Item Before Accessing It In TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have the array.

```
export const routes: {
  pathname: string
  id: TPageId
  access: 'public' | 'authenticated'
}[] = [
  { pathname: '/', id: 'login', access: 'public' },
  { pathname: '/login', id: 'login', access: 'public' },
  { pathname: '/404', id: '404', access: 'public' },
  { pathname: '/users', id: 'users', access: 'authenticated' },
  { pathname: '/runbooks', id: 'runbooks', access: 'authenticated' }
]
```

I'd like to check to see if a path exists before trying to copy it to a variable like this...

```
const pathId = routes.find(route => route.pathname === this.userReloadTarget).id
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` method of arrays.

```
var x = routes.filter(route => route.pathname === this.userReloadTarget);
if(x.length > 0)
    pathId = x[0].id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `route` returned from `find`.
However if all you care about is if a `route` exists in `routes` then you can use `some`.

But if you are trying to avoid getting errors since the returned `route` might be undefined when grabbing `id`, use something like this

```
const route = routes.find(route => route.pathname === this.userReloadTarget)
const pathId = route !== undefined ? route.id : '' // '' is the fallback
```

Answer (score 0):

The find() method returns the first value in the array, if an element in the array satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.So check the undefined before returning the id.

```
const route = routes.find(route => route.pathname === this.userReloadTarget);
const pathId = route!==undefined? route.id: '';
```